# Что нужно писать в .htaccess при переходе с https на локалку в http

Tags: .htaccess, http, битрикс, https

Сайт на Битриксе работает на https://mysyte.ru . Я его установил на локалку в OpenServer в nginx. Там сайт http://mysite-local.ru .

На сервере в .htaccess написано:

[image: Это фрагмент содержимого в .htaccess]

Что в .htaccess на локалке нужно писать при переходе на http?

Или как в OpenServer перейти на https?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^80$
RewriteRule .* http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение. В openserver: настройки -> сервер. поосмтрите какой порт у Вас для http и для https. В .htaccess поставьте нужный Вам порт (RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^80$ или RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -2):

Для OpenServer ничего не нужно менять. Просто в браузере в адресе сайта меняете протокол на https.

Вижу, что вы добавили код .htaccess. Нужно в нём не указывать явный адрес сайта. Будет примерно так.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L,QSA] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Я сделал так: просто в браузере набрал .https . Вышло сообщение: "Подключение не защищено
Злоумышленники могут пытаться похитить ваши данные с сайта exterier-local.ru (например, пароли, сообщения или номера банковских карт). Подробнее…
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID"

Comment: Так и должно быть. У вас же нет ssl-сертификата. Нажмите  в брауцзере дополнительно и добавьте исключение для сайта.

Comment: MAX, я не могу найти в Chrome где нужно сайт в исключения добавить. Настройки->Дополнительные настройки->Конфиденциальность и безопасность->Настройки контента->... А дальше что?